# Why is the relative identifier (rid) attribute in Active Directory null?

Tags: null, active-directory, attributes, sid

I am looking to resolve a foreign security principal (FSP) object. So I have a user object in one domain which is a member of a group in another domain. And I have my FSP as such:

CN=S-1-5-21-1943674009-604674534-4127978668-1107,CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,DC=external,DC=net

I know that S-1-5-21-1943674009-604674534-4127978668 is the domain SID of the remote domain, and 1107 is the rid corresponding to the actual user object in that domain. Currently, I can create a mapping between SIDs and the actual domain so I can perform searches like 
[ADSI]"LDAP://[domain]"

However, my issue is that the rid field of that user object is empty. So how can I pull back the specific user object if I can't search on the rid? What's more curious is that the rid value is clearly there in the objectSID attribute- so the user object has an rid value. But the actual attribute itself is null. So how can I use a search filter to get that entry explicitly? Is there certain AD configuration required to auto-populate that field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the object SID to find it in the external domain using e. g. DirectorySearcher. Moreover, you can bind directly to the object by it's SID in external domain (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675562(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
using (var entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://servername.contoso.com/<SID=S-X-X-XX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX-XXX>"))
        {
            entry.RefreshCache();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. That's essentially what I ended up doing: performing a subtree search on the container and pulling back all objectSIDs and checking each one to see if contained the rID from the FSP object. 

Since all the FSP object provides is the domain SID and the object's rID, binding to the server is just half the battle. I need to uniquely identify that object using only the rID once I've connected to the domain. And that's what I thought was the purpose of the rID attribute.